# Passing vector to a function gives error. c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

This is a noob question, sorry but, I just started using vectors in c++. Here's is the code I am struggling with.

```
int main()
{
  //some code
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  vector <int> a(n+1,0);
  int first=find(&a,d);  //d has some value from the upper portion of the code
}
int find(vector <int>* a,int o)
{
    int b=o;
    while(a->b!=0)
        b=a->b;
    return b;
}
```

Q1 : Why doesn't passing vector like find(a,d) work like it does in arrays.?

Q2 : In the find function, Why do I have to access the vector elements with "." or "->". Shouldn't a[b] work? If that is the correct way then why does a[b] work in the main function?

Q3 : What's wrong with the code? When I compile I get the error

```
In function ‘int find(std::vector<int>*, int)’:
error: ‘class std::vector<int>’ has no member named ‘b’
```

I understand the error, but then how do I access the required element?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I think you might need to find a book or online tutorial and start with the basics.

Comment: Note, if you want to use the vector as a pointer you can do => vector <int> *a = new vector<int>();

Comment: @demonofnight No, don't do that. The vector on the stack here is just fine, and preferable to heap allocation.

Comment: Yes, the stack is the best option, i just told him how to do that if he wanted to do that because it seems that he is a little confused about pointers, references in C++, in this option stack is the best option for sure.

Comment: @crashmstr This is the first time I am using vectors so yeah, its a very basic question. Sorry. I googled about this, but couldn't get any proper explaination.

Comment: @demonofnight you don't have to bring in dynamic allocation to explain pointers. The two are separate concepts.

Comment: @juanchopanza, that's true, i wanted to show dynamic allocation in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should study vectors, templates, the c++ way to do that.

Take a look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Q1 : Why doesn't passing vector like find(a,d) work like it does in arrays.?

Because it is not an array, its an object, so you can pass it as copy and not referece, you just pass it as a reference if you change the value.

Q2 : In the find function, Why do I have to access the vector elements with "." or "->". Shouldn't a[b] work? If that is the correct way then why does a[b] work in the main function?

a[position] returns the element
a->b dont work, you cannot access the b as an element
Use a->at(position) to access every element in the vector

Example (you can use iterators too)

```
for(int x=0; x<a->size();x++)
  cout << a->at(x);
```

Q3 : What's wrong with the code? When I compile I get the error

The previous question answers that.
You dont have the b element, the A is a vector it contains elements.
If you want to get the element at the position B do a->at(b).
If you want to find use

```
for(int x=0; x<a->size();x++)
  if(a->at(x) == b) return x; //returns the position
```

Comment: But then using a[b] in the main function doesn't give any error, whys that?

Comment: zack, its an operator, you should study operators in C++, the same way cout << works its because the compiler see an implementation for that. When the compiler see the [] it uses an method from the class called operator that implements how to use the []. You can implement it in any class by yourself.

Comment: @ChrisO: That would be `a->operator[](1)`

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, whoops, thanks for the correction.  `(*a)[1] = 42;` same as `a->operator[](1) = 42;`

Answer (score 6):

> Why doesn't passing vector like find(a,d) work like it does in arrays.?

Arrays are passed by "decaying" into a pointer to the first element; so they are effectively passed by reference.

Vectors are straightforward object types, passed by value unless the function is declared to take a reference. A function taking it by value will get a separate copy of it.

You could change the function to take the vector by reference:

```
void find(const std::vector<int> & a, int o);
                                 ^
```

The `const` is optional, but is a very good idea if the function doesn't need to modify the vector.

> In the find function, Why do I have to access the vector elements with "." or "->".

You don't. You access class members of the vector itself (such as `size()`) like that.

> Shouldn't `a[b]` work?

It would if `a` were an object or reference. Since it's a pointer, you have to dereference it, `(*a)[b]`

> If that is the correct way then why does `a[b]` work in the main function?

In the main function, 'a' is an object, so can be used directly as an operand.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying:

```
int b = o;
while(a->b!=0)
    b=a->b;
return b;
```

when you mean:

```
for(vector<int>::const_interator i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
    if (*a == o)
        return a.end() - i;
return a.size();
```